# Cannot call member function std::string class::function() without object

Tags: c++, string, function, object

I know it may seem like this has been asked before but I've looked around and the `static` method didn't work for me. Here's my code:

```
struct Customer {
public:
    string get_name();
private:
    string customer,first, last;
};
```

Here's where I call the function:

```
void creation::new_account() {
Customer::get_name(); //line it gives the error on.
}
```

Here's an example of some code that compiles fine.

```
struct Creation { public: string get_date(); private: string date; };
```

then I call it the same way

```
void Creation::new_account() { Creation::get_date();}
```

Hence my confusion why one works and the other doesn't.

EDIT: Ok I get it, I just realized I was calling a function of another struct inside a function definition that's part of a different class. I got it, thanks to all who answered

Comment: It's **not** *static*, you should call it through an object.

Comment: As pointed out, you missed out on declaring the function as static and hence the error. Can you put up the original code where "static" did not work for you?

Comment: @NotAgain sure it was this 'struct Customer {
public:
    static string get_name();
private:
    string customer,first, last;
};'

Comment: Let me guess. You wrote a static function get_name() and tried to return the contents of string customer,first or last. That would not work because static member functions have access to static data of the class only. And none of the three string data members are static here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not declared `static` (needs to be `static std::string get_name();`). However, `get_name()` for `Customer` is a specific attribute of a `Customer` instance so having it `static` does not make sense, that is the same name for all instances of `Customer`. Declare an object of `Customer` and use it. It would make sense to have the name provided to the constructor of `Customer`, as surely a customer cannot exist without a name:

```
class Customer {
public:
    Customer(std::string a_first_name,
             std::string a_last_name) : first_name_(std::move(a_first_name)),
                                        last_name_(std::move(a_last_name)) {}
    std::string get_name();
private:
    std::string first_name_;
    std::string last_name_;
};
```

Declare an instance of `Customer`:

```
Customer c("stack", "overflow");
std::cout << c.get_name() << "\n";
```

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to avoid passing an object through, but I suppose an empty object will work the same for my purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Since your `get_name` is not declared static, it is a member function.

You probably need some constructors in your `Customer` class. Assuming you have some, you could code

```
 Customer cust1("foo123","John","Doe");
 string name1 = cust1.get_name();
```

You need an object (here `cust1`) to call its `get_name` member function (or method).

Time to spend many hours reading a good C++ programming book.

Answer (score 0):

"The `static` method didn't work for me". It's not a method it's how the language works.

If you want to call some method without a concrete object, you need it to be static. Otherwise, you need an object.

Your code will work with one of the following :

```
struct Customer {
public:
    static string get_name();
private:
    string customer,first, last;
};
```

or

```
void creation::new_account() {
    Customer c;
    //stuff
    c.get_name();
}
```

Comment: Sorry I typed method, but semantics aside, what I mean by that is I typed static string get_name(); and the compiler complained.

But thanks the second worked. The reason I'm confused is because I have two other functions defined and declared the same and I created another just to be sure and without that function it compiled fine.

Comment: @Shilaly If the compiler complained when you actually used `static string get_name();`, then you made another error somewhere else...